# Google Services Version conflict

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am trying to fix this google services version error. I have been using Google services version 10.2.4 before for Google Sign in. Now since I want to integrate the Geofencing API into my application, as per what I have researched, it requires at least a minimal version of 11.0.0. But, I am not able to figure out what exactly the issue is. Please find below the error I get

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the 
google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at 
https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-
services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.4.
```

Please find below my app build.gradle file

**build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.group.projectga"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key",
                (project.findProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //Added this for Visual Gallery implementation - Start
    //Added this for Visual Gallery implementation - End

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.satsuware.lib:usefulviews:2.3.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.6'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.yesidlazaro:GmailBackground:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And also my build.gradle(Project) file.

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I followed a lot of Stack Overflow answers, and they said to add the plugin of the google services at the end. I have the plugin added right from the start and it seems not to work for this. I am trying to integrate the Geofencing API which requires the Google services version to be at least 11.0.0, but I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `firebase` and `com.google.android.gms` modules to the same version and at least 11.0.0 :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
```